# Installing App through TestFlight

Tags: xcode, provisioning, testflight

I am having an issue where:

When using the same computer I use to distribute apps to the app store, I am able to successfully package up an app so that beta testers can install apps on their devices using TestFlight.

I have a second computer that I have transferred all the code signing items from this computer over to, using the Export/Import Feature in XCode.

I have spent a few days trying to get the same process to work in TestFlight.
I am able to successfully archive the app and load it up to test flight, but when Beta Testers try to install the app, they get the familiar alert: "Unable to Download Application".

The installation icon gets about 3/4 of the way through the progress bar before this alert appears, which leads me to believe there's a problem with the provisioning profile.
I have tried to clean out and reinstall the Team's code signing Export file multiple times and have arrived at the result.

Additionally, I have gone through the process of getting rid of TestFlight, it's Provisioning Profile and Cleared Cookies, Data, & History from Safari.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have built and signed your App using a Provisioning Profile for **Distribution**!

Answer (score 0):

Use "Automatically manage Signing" option in XCode for code sign signing instead of exporting the Certificates and use there. I use 'fastlane' for pushing the builds to Testflight on daily basis. It saves developers time too.